# Looking for advise: Cleanest way to write scopes for filtering purposes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, code-cleanup

## Purpose of the post

I'm writing some code here to get an advise from people and see how they're writing `clean` ruby / rails code.

We're going to assume we have two models, `User` and `Project`. I wish to know how you'd create filters / scopes / methods for the best possible clean code.

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # first_name, last_name, email
  has_many :projects
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  # title, description, published
  belongs_to :user
end
```

## Method 1

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # first_name, last_name, email
  has_many :projects

  scope :with_first_name, -> (value) { where(first_name: value) }
  scope :with_last_name, -> (value) { where(last_name: value) }
  scope :with_email, -> (value) { where(email: value) }
  scope :with_project_name, -> (value) { joins(:projects).where(projects: { name: value }) }
end

class UserController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all

    if params[:first_name].present?
      @users = @users.with_first_name(params[:first_name])
    end

    if params[:last_name].present?
      @users = @users.with_last_name(params[:last_name])
    end

    if params[:email].present?
      @users = @users.with_email(params[:email])
    end

    if params[:project_name].present?
      @users = @users.with_project_name(params[:project_name])
    end

  end
end
```

This can be useful, but we're gonna have a very fat controller. When we add more filters, we're going to have more and more conditions to fill.

It can also be refactored to:

```rb
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all

    {
      first_name: :with_first_name,
      last_name: :with_last_name,
      email: :with_email,
      project_name: :with_project_name,
    }.each do |param, scope|
      value = params[param]
      if value.present?
        @users = @users.public_send(scope, value)
      end
    end

  end
end
```

but it will eliminate the possibility of having multiple params for a scope.

## Method 2

Same as above, but in the `model` instead of `controller`:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # first_name, last_name, email
  has_many :projects

  scope :with_first_name, -> (value) { value ? where(first_name: value) : all }
  scope :with_last_name, -> (value) { value.present ? where(last_name: value) : all }
  scope :with_email, -> (value) { value.present ? where(email: value) : all }
  scope :with_project_name, -> (value) { value.present? joins(:projects).where(projects: { name: value }) : all }

  def self.filter(filters)
    users = User.all

    {
      first_name: :with_first_name,
      last_name: :with_last_name,
      email: :with_email,
      project_name: :with_project_name,
    }.each do |param, scope|
      value = filters[param]
      if value.present?
        users = users.public_send(scope, value)
      end
    end

    users
  end
end

class UserController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.filter(
      params.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :project_name)
    )
  end
end
```

## Method 2

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # first_name, last_name, email
  has_many :projects

  scope :with_first_name, -> (value) { value ? where(first_name: value) : all }
  scope :with_last_name, -> (value) { value.present ? where(last_name: value) : all }
  scope :with_email, -> (value) { value.present ? where(email: value) : all }
  scope :with_project_name, -> (value) { value.present? joins(:projects).where(projects: { name: value }) : all }
end

class UserController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
    @users = @users.with_first_name(params[:first_name])
    @users = @users.with_last_name(params[:last_name])
    @users = @users.with_email(params[:email])
    @users = @users.with_project_name(params[:project_name])
  end
end
```

This way, we add the value validation on the scope level, and we remove the param checking in the controller.

However, the repetition here is tremendous and would always return values even if the scope doesn't apply. ( ex: empty string ).

## Final note

This post might not seem SO related, but would appreciate the input that anyone is going to give.

Comment: This question should potentially be migrated to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

### None of the above.

I would say that the cleanest way is to neither burdon your controller or User model further. Instead create a separate object which can be tested in isolation.

```
# Virtual model which represents a search query.
class UserQuery
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes

  attribute :first_name
  attribute :last_name
  attribute :email
  attribute :project_name

  # Loops through the attributes of the object and contructs a query 
  # will call 'filter_by_attribute_name' if present.
  # @param [ActiveRecord::Relation] base_scope - is not mutated
  # @return [ActiveRecord::Relation]
  def resolve(base_scope = User.all)
    valid_attributes.inject(base_scope) do |scope, key|
      if self.respond_to?("filter_by_#{key}")
        scope.merge(self.send("filter_by_#{key}"))
      else
        scope.where(key => self.send(key))
      end
    end
  end

  private 

  def filter_by_project_name
    User.joins(:projects)
        .where(projects: { name: project_name })
  end

  # Using compact_blank is admittedly a pretty naive solution for testing 
  # if attributes should be used in the query - but you get the idea.
  def valid_attributes
    attributes.compact_blank.keys
  end
end
```

This is especially relevant when you're talking about a User class which usually is the grand-daddy of all god classes in a Rails application.

The key to the elegance here is using [`Enumerable#inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) which lets you iterate accross the attributes and add more and more filters successively and [`ActiveRecord::SpawnMethods#merge`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge) which lets you mosh scopes together. You can think of this kind of like calling `.where(first_name: first_name).where(last_name: last_name)...` except in a loop.

Usage:

```
@users = UserQuery.new(
  params.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :project_name)
).resolve
```

Having a model means that you can use it for form bindings:

```
<%= form_with(model: @user_query, url: '/users/search') do |f| %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

And add validations and other features without making a mess.

Answer (score 1):

```
scope :filter_users, -> (params) { where(conditions).with_project_name }

scope :with_project_name, -> (value) { value.present? joins(:projects).where(projects: { name: value }) : all }


    
def process_condition(attr, hash)
  value = params[attr]  
  return hash if value.blank?
        
  hash[attr] = value                         
  hash
end
```

#This will return the conditions hash to be supplied to `where`. Since the param may have some other attribute which we may not need to apply filter, we construct conditions hash here.

```
def conditions
  hash = {}

  %i[last_name first_name email].each do |attr|
      hash = process_condition(attr, hash)
   end

  hash
end
```

Finally, I would recommend you to check out [ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#ransack-search-method) gem and the demo for the app is [ransack demo](http://ransack-demo.herokuapp.com/users/advanced_search). You can just use the search result of this gem by which you can support more filter options.

Comment: Hey @Aarthi, thanks for the response. However, `ransack` doesn't solve my problem, but your other solution might solve it.